# How to Connect to DB in Java - EDT time zone

Tags: java, mysql, selenium, jdbc

I have an issue that I am facing while I am trying to perform automate testing.
I want to connect to DB and perform select query.
Until now when The DB were in UTC time everything worked.
However today the DB team changed DB timezone to edt.

this is my code:

```
public class DBSupport {


    private  final String ID = "id";
   private final String CLASS = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
   DBConfiguration dbConfiguration;


   public String getUserIdFromDB(String newmail) throws Exception {
       dbConfiguration = new DBConfiguration();
       String query = "select id from users where email = '" + newmail + "' limit 1;";
       String userId = null;
       Class.forName(CLASS);
       Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbConfiguration.getUrl(), dbConfiguration.getUserName(), dbConfiguration.getPassword());
       Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
       ResultSet rowResult = stmt.executeQuery(query);
       if (rowResult.next()) {
           userId = rowResult.getString(ID);
           System.out.println(userId);
       }
       conn.close();
       return userId;
   }




}
```

and this is the exception that I get:

```
java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'EDT' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.

    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
```

this is the value in the build gradle

```
runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.17'
```

When I run this command in the DB

```
SELECT @@system_time_zone ;
```

The result is

```
EDT
```

I do not need the time zone for my testing just to connect to the DB.
untill yesterday in UTC it worked.
what I should add to my function?
regards

Comment: I do not see `EDT` in your code, nor any date-time handling in your code. What does date-time have to do with a query for email address and fetching user ID?

Comment: I do not know, but this is the exception. I do not want nothing from the date, just want to connect to db, and this is the exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the timezone using the `serverTimeZone` parameter in the connection string URL, like this...

```
"jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?serverTimezone=UTC"
```

see [this URL](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,677552,677574#msg-677574)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to roninjoe this is the solution

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://DB_IP:DB_PORT/DB_NAME?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC","db_user","db_password"));
```